# How to parse string to DateTime?

Tags: c#, string, parsing, datetime

I have product list and every product has create date in DateTime type. I want to take some products that created after my entering time in string type.

I enter **EnteredDate** in string type, like this **format : 05/16/2012**

```
1.    var dates = from d in Products
2.                where d.CreateDate >= DateTime.ParseExact( EnteredDate, "mm/dd/yy", null )
3.                select d;
```

In second line I got error as ***String was not recognized as a valid DateTime*** for "mm/dd/yy".
I also tried DateTime.Parse(), Convert.ToDateTime() and got same error.
How can I filter this product list by create date?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"mm" is minutes, and your year is 4 digits, not 2. You want "MM/dd/yyyy", if your format is *really* always that. How confident are you on that front? (In particular, if it's entered by a *user*, you should probably make your code culture-sensitive...)

I would suggest pulling the parsing part out of the query though, and also probably using the invariant culture for parsing if you've really got a fixed format:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(EnteredDate, "MM/dd/yyyy",
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var dates = Products.Where(d => d.CreateDate >= date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Call

```
DateTime.ParseExact(EnteredDate, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```